# How to print Map in dart console?

Tags: flutter, dart, console

I have this **Map** of headers for sending http requests including cookies in header. I have log the changes data in console to make sure it is working.

This is my **Map**:

`Map<String, String> headers = {};`

I tried doing this but it is not working:

`print(headers);`

I am getting this message:

> void print(Object? object)

Comment: Can you include more context, current header should print `{}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to print entry by entry from the Map.

It would be like the following example:

```dart
final headers = <String, String>{ 
  'AUTHORIZATION': 'test:test',
  'ACCEPT': 'application/json'
};

void main() {
  for (final e in headers.entries) {
    print('${e.key} = ${e.value}');
  }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
AUTHORIZATION = test:test
ACCEPT = application/json
```

Answer (score 0):

dart allow printing maps

check if you are printing headers map rather than something else

if you still have your problem maybe provide some code snippets ?[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).